# how can I build flexible data model in django

Tags: django

I am a beginner using django, I want to build a flexible data model like this:(see the picture)

Uses can add new attribute (attr 4, 5..) without changing the database (do not add new columns)[data model pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAiLu.png)
How can I realize it in model, view and form with the function of creating Item and searching items on selected attrs?
The main problem confused me is that I cannot link form with model since the attribute is actually values not truly attributes.

Comment: Please see the data model pic for detail, sorry I do not know the right way to upload picture

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to create an [EAV data model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). Your other option would be to use a JSON store to allow for changing columns per user.